# EntityFrameworkCore does not exist in the namespace Microsoft

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework-core

I am trying to walk through this tutorial here.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/data/ef-mvc/intro

However after successfully installing EntityFrameworkCore in the package manager console using the command:

Install-Package Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer

then running a dotnet restore successfully in the cmd, the project does not register EntityFrameworkCore. In the .csproj file you can see the line

```
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer" Version="1.1.1" />
```

Unfortunately whenever I add a using statement with Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore in a file I get the error mentioned in the title. Any idea why this might be happening?

Comment: Just to say, it's now July 2017, and this code is still a bit flakey.  If you get errors like this, do try restarting VS2017.   I know, I know... it's a bit ridiculous, but that did fix a few ASP.Net Core issues for me today.. and all I was doing was following Microsoft's own tutorial.   https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/get-started/aspnetcore/existing-db#comments-container

Comment: Its May 2023, if someone has this issue, be sure not to have the repository for GitHub in the same folder (GitHub desktop can create it for you in there automatically).

Answer (score 64, accepted):

I solved this problem by:

(1) Right clicking the project in the Solution Explorer

(2) Clicking unload project

(3) Click edit the .csproj and check if there is a Package Reference to EF

(4) Right clicking the project again in the Solution Explorer

(5) Then clicked reload project

Now it recognizes EntityFrameworkCore and there are no more build errors

Comment: Solve my problem perfectly . Even if don't understand why i should unload and reload my projet ... So weird

Comment: This worked partially for me but then one of my namespaces wasn't recognized. I had to close and reopen VS for everything to work properly

Comment: But it does not help me. It just update .csproj file.  The type or namespace name 'EntityFrameworkCore' does not exist in the namespace 'Microsoft'

Answer (score 26):

In Visual Code:

<kbd>Ctrl + Shift + P</kbd> => **Restart OmniSharp**

Comment: this should be one of the first things to do! Thanks for this.

Answer (score 10):

Go to NuGet browser and install Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore!

Comment: For those using VS Code or the terminal, ```dotnet add package Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore```

Answer (score 9):

You missed a required Nuget Package, according to [microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/get-started/install/), you will need to install 3 packages in total, but in my case, it is only required 2 packages as the following:

- Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer
- Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools

Hope this can solve your problem.

Answer (score 7):

If using VS Code, the solution that worked for me:

In the terminal type:

```
dotnet add package Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore
```

After adding package, `Ctrl + Shift + P` -> **Restart OmniSharp**

Answer (score 5):

Copying the following code into the TodoApi.csproj from https://github.com/aspnet/Docs/tree/master/aspnetcore/tutorials/first-web-api/sample/TodoApi worked for me.

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp2.0</TargetFramework>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <Folder Include="wwwroot\" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.All" Version="2.0.0" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <DotNetCliToolReference Include="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Tools" Version="2.0.0" />
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

Microsoft.AspNetCore.All may be excessive but it includes EntityFrameworkCore etc

Answer (score 3):

In visual Studio, go to  ->  **Project** -> **Manage NuGet Packages..** ->
[image: In Visual]

Select **Microsoft Entity framework Core**. The click on **Add package** on the bottom right corner button.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

1. Go to Tools in your visual studio  » NuGet Package Manager » Package Manager Console
2. type->

   install-package microsoft.entityframeworkcore.sqlserver

Comment: Perhaps just `install-package microsoft.entityframeworkcore` will work in this instance.

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming this is the same issue I encountered with:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/razor-pages/?view=aspnetcore-6.0

The getting started directions include a section that lead you to believe you need to add the following -

```
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using RazorPagesMovie.Data;
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

// Add services to the container.
builder.Services.AddRazorPages();

builder.Services.AddDbContext<RazorPagesMovieContext>(options => 
       options.UseSqlServer(builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("RazorPagesMovieContext")));

var app = builder.Build();
```

However I determined that if you skip this and continue the tutorial, it is handled later on...

Answer (score 0):

Clean up the .csproj file so if you see something like...

```
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools" Version="2.2.4">
   <PrivateAssets>all</PrivateAssets>
   <IncludeAssets>runtime; build; native; contentfiles; analyzers</IncludeAssets>
</PackageReference>
```

Change it to :

```
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools" Version="2.2.4" />
```

Answer (score 0):

From one of the other comments about the package.config file,  double checking...  Seems, my issue appeared that the targetFramework="net472" in the package.config file didn't match the project's .Net version.  The project is using 4.7.2 but the package file was "471",   updating the targetFramework in the package.config to "472" the problems went away :)

Seem in the past never had many issues with mixing 4.x.y, as long as 4.x were the same no troubles, as of late, sure seems .Net want 4.x.y to all match...

```
`<packages>
   <package id="EntityFramework" version="6.2.0" targetFramework="net472" />
</packages>`
```

Answer (score 0):

I've passed for something similar. The dependencies were installed but VSCode was not recognizing them (red waved line under the references).

I ran: `ctrl + shift + p` and then `.NET Restart Language Server`.

[image]

Answer (score -1):

I had to lower the version of Entity Framework from 6.2 to 6.0

Answer (score -1):

Use the nugget packege manager on VS code and add Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore that way and the issue will be solved it will also place it into the .csproj

`<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore" Version="5.0.16"/>`

Answer (score -1):

I had the same problem in Visual Studio Code, it was decided that it was necessary to choose a project in which an error with the help of Omnisharp:Select Project through the ctrl + shift + p