# Can't reference Entity Framework Core in .NET 5

Tags: c#, visual-studio-code, .net-core, entity-framework-core

I'm using Visual Studio Code to build a class library with .NET 5 and Entity Framework Core.

However, I can't make reference to Entity Framework Core and I keep getting errors as if it doesn't exist.

This is the project file:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net5.0</TargetFramework>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore" Version="5.0.7" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Relational" Version="5.0.7" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer" Version="5.0.7" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools" Version="5.0.7" />
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

All the package reference were included using `dotnet add package`.

These are the attempts I already made:

- Restart Omni sharp
- Restore the packages (`dotnet package restore`)
- Use a lower version of Entity Framework Core (5.0.0)

The specific problem and error message is here and was here all the time, so no other intelligent editor may close this question again:

The result continues to be the same, I get an error message on the `using` telling the `EntityFrameworkCore` namespace doesn't exist in the Microsoft namespace. However, the IntelliSense shows `EntityFrameworkCore`.

What else could I try?

P.S.: As required for the question not get closed - I already tried all the options on the other question in stackoverflow, all the options that fit on this scenario, and they don't work. The other question: [EntityFrameworkCore does not exist in the namespace Microsoft](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43008666/entityframeworkcore-does-not-exist-in-the-namespace-microsoft)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43008666/entityframeworkcore-does-not-exist-in-the-namespace-microsoft

Comment: Does this answer your question? [EntityFrameworkCore does not exist in the namespace Microsoft](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43008666/entityframeworkcore-does-not-exist-in-the-namespace-microsoft)

Comment: @BarışCanYılmaz  no, it doesn't. Before asking, I tested all those options.

Comment: Hi @DennesTorres, this question caught the attention of some members of the product teams that work on these products, but Stack Overflow is not the best medium for them to help resolve it. Can you file an issue here? https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn

Comment: Since your original question (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68314949/cant-reference-entity-framework-core-in-net-5-and-visual-studio-code) has been reopened, I think this one should be closed as duplicate of that one.